# Can I parse raw_body in webhook without code? If in code, how to get prior step values?

Tags: webhooks, zapier

Help me decide between a Raw and standard Webhook, please.

I receive JSON data on a Webhook.

I want to first filter for validity, and if valid, continue to post the JSON payload to a further downstream webhook.

I want use to a regular Filter action to filter (avoiding code). I understand actions require the JSON to be parsed out into structured fields.

When valid, I need to re-POST the payload (via Custom Request) to a downstream webhook.

(BTW my incoming webhook payload is well-formed JSON. When I use a standard webhook Zapier has no problem getting the fields.)

For the trigger, I believe that either I need to use "Catch Raw" to receive the (unparsed) raw_data and then work out some sort of step to parse out this into fields, or trigger on a regular (pre-parsed) webhook and build some action to make the JSON from all the current field values.

I trigger on a regular webhook, can I aggregate the current values of the (normal) fields into JSON structure to POST (i.e. a raw_body equivalent) of the trigger and/or later-step output values?

If I have to do this in a code action, is there a variable that can access the  JSON raw_data of the trigger later action-steps?

Thanks, Martin

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I'm going to answer my own question.

CMD Line:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -d "{\"username\":\"abc\",\"password\":\"abc\"}" https://hooks.zapier.com/XXXXXXXXXX
```

(If testing from Windows, ensuring to use double quotes (not single) and backslash escaping them individually is paramount)

[image: Catch Raw Hook Trigger and subsequent JavaScript Code Action to extract]

Core output:
[image: Output]

inputData is Zapier's contract for all incoming data. It's an object. When I set up the headers for the action I map it to the attribute name I chose: "raw_body"; for testing I also showed it output attribute stringified.

What I was looking for is to replicate the expanding effect of a normal Catch using a Raw Catch. JSON.parse(raw_body) turns the string representation into nested objects.

The output variable is how Zapier's contract to downstream. Note what we get is what we put in output, plus the "id" attribute, which Zapier injected.

Meanwhile, anything written to console.log ends up in runtime_meta, in logs[]. An annoying thing is that runtime errors cause runtime_meta to not show up.

Runtime Metadata
[image: Output Metadata]

---

In my first sample I placed them under parsed, but in this next I've used parsed whole of output to equal parsed, and then injected raw_body and injected_other also, for good measure
[image]

[image]
(logs ommitted)

Comment: The most important source code for everyone who doesn't want to type it again:
`var parsed = JSON.parse(inputData.raw_body);
var output = { type: typeof(inputData), parsed: parsed };`